# While Using file_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, package

while testing file_picker package, I found these errors:

```
Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 244:5                   _operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 56:40                                          get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 83:44                                               get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 156:50                                              get isAndroid
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
packages/file_picker/src/file_picker.dart 50:18                                   _setPlatform
packages/file_picker/src/file_picker.dart 40:44                                   get _instance
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1430:8  get
packages/file_picker/src/file_picker.dart 42:37                                   get platform
packages/whatsapp_clone/webPages/login_signup_page.dart 30:65                     chooseImage
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/whatsapp_clone/webPages/login_signup_page.dart 28:13                     chooseImage
packages/whatsapp_clone/webPages/login_signup_page.dart 88:33                     <fn>
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1183:21                               handleTap
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 275:24                              invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 652:11                                     handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 309:5                                      [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 242:7                                      handlePrimaryPointer
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 630:9                               handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:7                            [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:7           forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                          [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                           route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 488:5                                  handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 468:14                                 dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 439:11                                dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 413:7                                  [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 376:5                                  handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 323:7                                  [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 292:9                                  [_handlePointerDataPacket]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1289:5                                invoke1
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 273:5                                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 168:30                                    [_onPointerData]
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 791:20                                    <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 720:7                                     <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 317:9                                     loggedHandler
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39  dcall
```

and the button of selection doesn't respond. What must I do?

I tried selecting an image by file_picker package. But, when clicking the button, I saw these errors above
The link of [the project](https://github.com/sabriboulahia2011/whatsapp-clone1.git) is there

Comment: Please provide code that throws error.